# non-root user throws permissions error trying to READ a file in volume

Tags: docker, docker-container, system-administration

In my Dockerfile, I create a non-root user and set permissions on the binary and non-root user's workspace with the following:

```
RUN groupadd --gid 1000 non-root-user \
    && useradd -g 1000 non-root-user \
    && chown -R non-root-user:non-root-user /var/workspace/non-root-user \
    && chmod -R 550 /var/workspace/non-root-user \   # location of binary, sym-link to /run


USER non-root-user
```

When I start the container and run a binary that tries to read a config.json file, the binary exits out saying

```
non-root-user@4bd15417ffdc:/$ ./run start
Error: Permission denied (os error 13)
```

Like mentioned above, the binary has 550.
in the volume containing the config.json file, the config.json has:

`-rw-rw-rw- 1 non-root-user non-root-user 1464 Feb 27 18:49 config.json`

Yet the binary cannot access it.
I've tried:

- passing in the volume with `:Z`
- chmod 777 config.json
- changing entrypoint to a shell script that runs `su -s /bin/bash -c "/run start" non-root-user

getting desperate and running out of ideas here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you starting the container?  Where does that shell prompt come from?  What is `run`, and what makes this `config.json` file important?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze,
- I am starting the container with `docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -it -v $(volume):/app $(imageId)`
- `run` is a binary that will end up being the actual entrypoint of the dockerfile
- config.json is important because it feeds the config settings into the `run` binary